# How to prevent ubuntu from connecting to wifi hotspots automatically

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, hot-spot

Note: this question is distinct from "How to disable automatically connecting to WiFi?", as I do not wish to disable automatic WiFi connection in general.

Problem: The Ubuntu WiFi module connects automatically in priority with WiFi networks without a password, even if there is a already known password-protected WiFi network nearby. Worse, most of the times these "unprotected" networks are in fact hotspots that require authentification from the browser.
Example: I am at home, and most of the times my Ubuntu laptop will connect by itself to a nearby hotspot instead of choosing my local ADSL box (password-protected, with a password that is already known by the computer). I then have to select my own WiFi network manually.

Is there a way to disable automatic connection to /all/ hotspots ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable automatically connecting to WiFi?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154880/how-to-disable-automatically-connecting-to-wifi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stop Ubuntu from automatically connecting to Wifi connections without deleting the connection entry itself.

Go to: `network-indicator` > *Edit Connections* > *Wireless*

Select the entry that you do not want automatically connecting. Once selected/highlighted, click on the "Edit" button on the right side of the window. At the top of the window that opens, you will see an option to disable  "Connect automatically".

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed ! And it's also accessible easily in Gnome-Shell. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like the [discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1213468.html) we had in 2009-2010. This also is a duplicate of [How to disable/enable automatically connecting to WiFi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154880/how-to-disable-automatically-connecting-to-wifi?rq=1) which contains the answer to your question:

> Click on Wi-fi Icon >> Edit Connections >> Then, Click On Wireless Tab, Delete The Wireless Connections That You Don't want to Use or You Want Ubuntu To Stop Automatically Connecting To Them.

Comment: Won't they appear again next time a wifi scan is performed ?