# How can I block a specific wireless network using the terminal

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point

I am trying to block a specific Wireless Network such as "Router_Home" because everytime I wake up my laptop the first thing that the Network Manager does is to try connecting to this Network.

Can you show me how to do that using the terminal or/and GUI ?

EDIT: I know I can uncheck the "connect automatically" option. But I want to know how to block a wireless network totally.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: If it's secured, then removing the secrets will properly prevent it from connecting to it... Or does that not really do what you want?

Comment: @gertvdijk let me try that and I will update you. But It's nice to know how to block a wireless network using the terminal ^_^ So if anyone knows please do share your solution with us

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/154880/62483

Comment: I've added a bounty to the master questions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154880/how-to-disable-enable-automatically-connecting-to-wifi). Hopefully you'll get the answer you want :)

Comment: Please see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/154884/44179 Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Seth, thank you for following up after my question :-). The answer you provided(command line) would block the wireless interface. As for my question, I want to block "Router_home" aka a specific wireless Access point. I think I came to a conclusion that its impossible to do that without using a 3rd part app such NM or WICD :-p

Comment: @Suhaib Oh.. kinda got the question wrong :/

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you can just delete the connection from network manager by going to the network manager -->edit-->wireless then highlight the connection and click delete.

There is also a package in the repos called nmcli that is a command line interface for network manager, but I haven't tried it.