# How to automatically connect to Home wireless network after waking from a suspension?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, laptop, suspend

So after some research, I've found that it's supposed to disconnect from wifi when it's suspended, however what I can't seem to figure out, is why my laptop is automatically connecting to some other network instead of my own when it comes back on after being suspended.

I've already had a look at the Network settings, and the Home network is set to connect automatically, the only thing I can see of why it might be choosing this other available network over my Home network, is that this other one is not password protected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you de-select auto connect on the other wifi network?

Comment: I have this question which might help, http://askubuntu.com/questions/256072/how-can-i-block-a-specific-wireless-network-using-the-terminal-or-and-gui

Answer (score -3):

You should deselect the network that connects automatically and erase also all the other wireless networks that are memorized in your wireless interface. Then reboot the computer and see how it goes.

Comment: This answer is too localized (in my opinion) to be a proper answer. It has no evidence supporting *why* you should complete these steps, and it's a little too open-ended, if you ask me. This type of discussion-based 'guess' is better to be added as a comment once you gain enough reputation. Please consider this and read the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) to check what an ideal, acceptable answer is like. Thanks for your consideration :)