# Connect to only one specific wireless network if available?

Tags: wireless, networking, xubuntu

I have a home server running Xubuntu 12.10 and it is connected by WLAN to my home network.

The problem is that when the router crashes, the server loses connection and tries to connect to another network. My neighbours have open wireless connections and I'm afraid that my server might connect to their networks.

I want to make the server to connect to my home network, when it's available, and when not, just to wait for it to become available.  If I need to explain this scenario more or to answer further questions, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable/enable automatically connecting to WiFi?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154880/how-to-disable-enable-automatically-connecting-to-wifi)

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. I'm really sorry, the question may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never connected the server to your neighbors or any other WIFI network, it should not auto connect to one. *UNLESS* you have configured it to autoconnect.

here is a previous post that has answered a similar problem.

[How to disable/enable automatically connecting to WiFi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154880/how-to-disable-enable-automatically-connecting-to-wifi)